# How to limit number of ODBC connections from a .Net web application?

Tags: c#, .net, connection, odbc, pooling

I have created a .Net 3.5 web service in C# that communicates to a Progress OpenEdge database through ODBC.

This database has been set up to only allow 10 simultaneous connections on the user account the web service is using (third party restriction).

I am running into a huge problem when the web service gets a lot of simultaneous requests and tries to connect to the database for each of these requests. When the connection limit is exceeded, the database will reject new incoming connections for a couple of minutes.

The web service is running on windows server 2008.
Connection pooling is enabled for the ODBC driver.

I somehow will have to restrict the number of connections that my web service is trying to make, but I don't know how. The Progress OpenEdge ODBC driver that I am using, does not support a maximum pool size argument.

I've been reading a lot of documentation from microsoft on the subject, but all I have been able to conclude is:

- Connection pooling is enabled by default
- Connection pooling cannot be configured from my application
- Default maximum pool size is 100
- There is no way to change the maximum pool size unless the driver you are using supports it

Can someone confirm this, and/or suggest a method to limit the number of connections in this situation? Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the WCF approach as mentioned or you could implement the connection pooling programmatically.

```
public interface IService
{
    void Execute(Action<IDbConnection> command);
    T Execute<T>(Func<IDbConnection, T> command);
}

public sealed class ConnectionManager : IService
{
    public const int MaxConnections = 10;

    private readonly string _connectionString;
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _workers = new SemaphoreSlim(0, MaxConnections);

    public ConnectionManager(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public void Execute(Action<IDbConnection> command)
    {
        lock(_workers)
        {
            using(var connection = new OdbcConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                command(connection);
            }
        }
    }

    public T Execute<T>(Func<IDbConnection, T> command)
    {
        lock(_workers)
        {
            using(var connection = new OdbcConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                return command(connection);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `SemaphoreSlim` will prevent more than 10 connections from opening assuming the code that is called doesn't try anything sneaky.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I did think of using a semaphore here, but I thought it wouldn't work because of scope issues. What is the scope of the semaphore variable here? If my web service gets requests from different users / machines, won't IIS create multiple instances of my class and thus create multiple instances of the semaphore, making it useless?

Comment: You can either make the `SemaphoreSlim` static or create a static instance of `ConnectionManager`. I was thinking the latter case since you may have multiple Progress OpenEdge servers which would have different `ConnectionManager`.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that static variables are also application wide in web applications. Well that's good to know. To me this appears to be the neatest solution; easy to implement and I prefer the idea of having the application manage the connections itself. I will try and test this on friday and I will post the result here.

Comment: I promised to return with some feedback, so here it is;

I have been able to implement connection pooling with a semaphore (semaphoreslim isn't available in .net 3.5). However I had to make some changes to the example you provided in order to make it work:

1) instead of using lock, which essentially just makes any variable work as a mutex, the semaphore has to be used with waitone() and release() to acquire and release a slot
2) the semaphore has to be initialised with MaxConnections,MaxConnections instead of 0,MaxConnections. Otherwise it starts with all slots being taken.

Comment: I am accepting this as the answer, because it pointed me in the right direction. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You could consider configuring the WCF service to only allow 10 simultaneous requests.  This will only work if each request uses no more than 1 db connection, of course, any may or may not make sense for your particular service.

Comment: I am actually using an ASP.NET web service. Is it still possible to configure this? If so; how? Do I configure this in IIS, or in code, or in web.config?

Comment: You can do this in IIS config:
http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/limits

Comment: Thanks. While I am not using it for this one, it's good to know :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like the architecture of your application should be reconsidered. 
I would deal with this situation by having a separate thread (or threads ) that connects to the database in your web service. The web service could then manage the thread(s) that connects to the database.

For simplicity assume only one connection to the database.

When you get a request for the web service the the service will put the request into the queue of the shared database thread.

The database thread will just sit there until there is something in the queue to process.
When there is it will take it off the queue and send the request to the server.

It is likely that you will have a bit of extra work here in picking up the returned data too because the data will be returned on a different thread to the thread it was requested on.

The same principle could be used having multiple threads ( one per allowed connection ) 
You would then write a class to manage the threads so the each thread just took the next item from the queue.